# What does char* exactly define? If it define a string array, how do I output a single element?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, output

```
int main()
{
int a = 0;
int BUFSIZE = 1000;
char *string1[20];
FILE *fp1 = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
if (fp1 == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening");
    return 0;
}
string1[a] = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE);
while (fgets(string1[a], BUFSIZE, fp1)!=NULL)
{
    a++;
    string1[a] = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE);
} 
printf("%c", string1[3]);
}
```

Hi, I get the above code, which reads a string from a text file and store it in an array. Now I want to output a certain element of array string1, but apparently printf doesn't work. Besides, what does char *string1[20] exactly define? Does it have something to do with pointer? Thank you！

Comment: Not something,it has everything to do with pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char *string1[20]
```

declares an array, named `string1`, of 20 *pointers to `char`*. Thus `string1[3]` is a pointer to `char`, and not a `char`, as would be required for the `%c` format.

Since `string1[3]` was - if at all - filled via `fgets`, it contains a 0-terminated string, so you can print it out using

```
printf("%s\n", string1[3]);
```

If you want to print a single character, you'd use

```
printf("%c\n", string1[3][4]);
```

for example.

Comment: And 20 means 20 pointers to char? But string1 can store a string with a length longer than 20, right? I once edited input1.txt, typed a very long string, and the code can still read it correctly, why?

Comment: What, exactly, doesn't work? Of course you must not print out `string1[i]` if that hasn't been filled with a 0-terminated string by `fgets` (and been allocated enough memory before).

Comment: Both  printf("%s\n", string1[3]);  and  printf("%c\n", string1[3][4]);  make the program break...string1 was filled via fgets

Comment: `string1` can hold 20 pointers to `char`. Each of them can be a pointer to a single `char` or, more commonly, a pointer to a block of memory that is used as an array of `char`s. After you allocated `string1[a] = malloc(BUFSIZE);`, check whether `malloc` returned `NULL`, if not, `string1[a]` now contains a pointer to a memory block large enough to hold `BUFSIZE` `char`s, for example a 0-terminated string of length at most `BUFSIZE-1` (not counting the 0-terminator). If you then call `fgets(string1[a], BUFSIZE, fp1);`, and that doesn't return `NULL`, the memory block then contains a C-string.

Comment: @phil You should not - and in the posted code do not - fill `string1` via `fgets`, but `string1[3]` (well, `string1[i]` for `0 <= i < k` with `k <= 20`). If you fill more than three strings (`string1[3]` is the fourth in the array), printing `string1[3]` ought to work. If less, `string1[3]` is either not allocated (then trying to print it is bad), or not filled with a 0-terminated string (then trying to print it is bad).

Comment: Sorry, finally I find out I misunderstood the whole thing. I thought string1 holds only one string, 'ACBDABC' for example, and each element of it points to a character, for instance, string1[3] should be 'D', but I was wrong. String1 actually holds multiple strings, and string1[3] indicates the forth string. Since I only read one string into string1, if I want to print the forth character of the string, I should use printf("%c\n", string1[0][3]); and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
char* string1[20];
```

defines a pointer to a `char` array, which is not what you want. You want a `char` array.

If you remove the `*` in the declaration of `string1` like this

```
char string1[20];
```

it should work.

Edit: Daniel Fisher is right...it's an array of pointers to char.
Nevertheless it is not clear, what you attempt to do.
If you want to just read the file into a single array, you could do this:

```
int BUFSIZE = 1000;
char string[BUFSIZE];
FILE *fp1 = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
if ( fp1 == 0 )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening");
    return 0;
}
fgets(string1, BUFSIZE, fp1);
printf("%s", string1); // print the whole file content
printf("%c", string1[3]); // print the fourth character
```

Comment: You are right, actually I just need to read the file, which contains only one string, into a single array. Each element of the array should indicate a character, not a string. So the code I posted is not appropriate. I tried your code, but got no result...it just exited directly

Answer (score 0):

It has everything to do with pointers.

To print value of `string1` use the value at opperator `*`
Basically the string1 does not actually contain anything it points to the data. So you dont want the value of string1[20]  , you want the value at it

```
 printf("%c", *string1[19]);
```

Should do

Comment: Try *string1[20] instead, and it might crash because the array as 20 elements and you're dereferencing the 21st element.

Comment: It is still not right, as of now, you are taking the address of the the 20th char pointer.

Comment: Didn't work...I read a string with length 7, printf("%c", &string1[19]) gave me a meaningless value, then I tried printf("%c", &string1[3]), but got a blank.

Comment: @phil , you should not expect a meaningful value at 20th place whem you are reading a string of length 7 . The

Answer (score 0):

`char*` defines a pointer to a char.

`char string[20]` defines an array of 20 chars.

`char* string[5]` defines an array of 5 char* or pointer to char.

If you have an array of char and you want to use it as a null terminated string for example, you need to take the address of the first element like so:

```
char array[20];
char* pointer = &array[0];
```

So in your case, `char* string[20]` is an array of char pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`char *string[20];` Is an array of pointers to "char", it can be used to store letters as an array of "strings". I wrote "string" because C does not have the string datatype unlike C++ for instance.